# React-Native IoS Background Location

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, react-native-ios

Has anyone actually found a way to get background location on react-native-ios that Apple will actually allow on the public store?

I've tried [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) which works brilliantly does exactly what I want, but Apple simple won't let you deploy to their public store with the required permissions. So can't publish the app and have to go back to the drawing board to find a different solution.

I've tried react-native-begin-background-task with BLE which doesn't work, and playing audio is apparently a hard no.

There must be some way to do this? How do apps like [Strava](https://www.strava.com/) get this right?

Comment: Did you figure this out?